# Handling two physical buttons at a same time

Tags: android

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN && keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP )               
        textView.setText("both buttons are  pressed");                 
    return true;                           
}
```

The problem is, when I use single comparison in if () then it works correctly. but when I use 2 comparison in single if() using && then it doesn't  work. actually I want to perform action when volume up and volume down buttons are pressed at a same time.

Comment: Hint: on **key** down. There's only one key event registered at a time

Answer (score 0):

onKeyDown() is fired twice when each key is pressed down. what you need is to use two individual if()s which increment an int onKeyDown that is initialised to zero and decrement it onKeyUp then also each check if the int is equal to 2 in onKeyUp, if true carry out an action u require which will be in a method you call

Sudo code:

```
int i = 0;
public void onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){

   if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){

     i++;
    }

   if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP ){
     i++;
   }

    if(i == 2 ){
      action();
    }

}

public void onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){

if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
   i--;
  }

 if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP ){
    i--;
  }
}


 private void action(){

  // AND ACTION!!!
}
```